# getting gridview columns values in array list

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, checkbox

I have gridview in which i have check box control Like this image.

[image]

Problem is that i want to use the values of checked status.Mean if status is checked then i want assign the values to a string like this `867,864`.I have tried a little code here but its not working properly

```
For Each gvrow As GridViewRow In GridView5.Rows
            Dim chkbox As CheckBox = CType(gvrow.FindControl("chkStatusGM"), CheckBox)
            If chkbox.Checked Then
                Dim bpv As String = GridView5.Rows(0).Cells(3).Text
                Response.Write(bpv)
End If
        Next
```

But the out put is `867867` not `867,864` which i want.Please anyone help to get the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Dim bpv As String = ""

For Each gvrow As GridViewRow In GridView5.Rows
    Dim chkbox As CheckBox = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("chkStatusGM"); 
    If chkbox!= null && chkbox.Checked Then
        If bpv <> "" Then
            bpv += ","
        End If
        bpv += gvrow.Cells(3).Text
    End If
 Next
 Response.Write(bpv)
```

Comment: Sir Now Output is `867,867` but i want `867,864` according to checkbox selection

Comment: Sir I think u r fixing the value of ist row of cell3 not dynamicaly according to checkbox selection coz i have selected  `BPV 863` BUT it again returned the `868,868`

Comment: Now i change from  "bpv += GridView5(0).Cells(3).Text" to " bpv += gvrow.Cells(3).Text".. Now i  running fine

Comment: Because , first i am findout fix row(0) inside of code....Now i fix it and solved

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to give you the answer in C# as I am not familiar in VB you can use the online converters to convert the code into the VB

The mistake I found is that you should take an index and increment so that to detect the next check box checked as below:

```
int j = 0;
foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in GridView1.Rows)
{
    CheckBox chkSel = (CheckBox)gvRow.FindControl("SelectCheck");
    if (chkSel.Checked)
    {
        string Delete = Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows[j].Cells[3].Text);
        //Cells[3] is the column to get one by one rows ceslls[3] columns
        Bal_add.Delete(Delete);
    }
    j++;
}
```

for example in this case `j` is the index and increment it.

Hope this helps :D